# How do I use a custom namespaced derive-macro attribute on a type instead of inside the type?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I'd like to create a custom derive macro that uses the new namespaced attribute syntax: `example::attr`. I've been able to get this to work with attributes within the type (on a struct field or an enum variant, for example), but not when applied to the type itself.

**src/main.rs**

```
use repro_derive::Example;

#[derive(Example)]
#[example::attr]     // Does not work
struct Demo {
    #[example::attr] // Works
    field: i32,
}

fn main() {}
```

The procedural macro itself does nothing, other than to declare that `example::attr` is a valid attribute.

**repro-derive/src/lib.rs**

```
extern crate proc_macro;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(Example, attributes(example::attr))]
pub fn example_derive(_input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    TokenStream::new()
}
```

Compiling yields:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `example`
 --> src/main.rs:4:3
  |
4 | #[example::attr]
  |   ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `example`
```

Switching to a non-namespaced form of the attribute (`example_attr`) works fine.

---

I'm using Rust 1.32.0. The project layout is

```
$ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── repro-derive
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
$ cat Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "repro"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Author"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
repro-derive = { path = "repro-derive" }
```

**repro-derive/Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "repro-derive"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Author"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace declared in the `proc_macro_derive` attribute is entirely *ignored*, and this is a [known bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55168). Because of this bug, the following code can be compiled, though it shouldn't be.

```
#[derive(Example)]
#[attr]             // Works (but shouldn't)
struct Demo {
    #[lolwut::attr] // Works (but shouldn't)
    field: i32,
}
```

Until the bug is fixed, you should keep using the non-namespaced form (`example_attr`).

Also, according to this bug report, as of Rust 1.33.0 there is *no* way to achieve what OP wants via proc-macros, and how to allow `#[example::attr]` to work is still under design.

Comment: Is there *any* way to use such a syntax currently? If not, do you know if there will be?